# JNI - how to fill a String passed from C++ to Java

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to send empty string from c++ to java and the java function should fill this string so the c++ could use it.

I dont want the Java code to return a value. I want it to fill a received String.

I thought using StringBuilder and this is how my java function looks like:

```
private static void setValue(StringBuilder param) {
param.append(value);
}
```

This is how my C++ code looks like:

```
jclass class = env->FindClass("class");
jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID(class, "fillValue", "
(Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;)V");
```

What should i send to the function so it would work?
I tried sending jstring but it doesnt work.

**UPDATE:**
Tried the following code in c++ side but it didnt work:

```
char* str;
jstring string = env->NewStringUTF( str );

env->CallStaticObjectMethod(class,method, string);
const char* test = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you tried?

Comment: Yep, added it to the question

Comment: But your method takes a `StringBuilder`, and you are passing a `String`.

Comment: How can i pass StringBuilder? or are there other ways to achieve what i want?

Comment: `class` is a C++ reserved word.  `jclass class = env->FindClass("class");` shouldn't even compile.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: To pass a new **StringBuilder** to a Java method, you should find `jclass SBclass = env->FindClass("java/lang/StringBuilder")` and then `jmethodID  SBconstructor = env->GetMethodID(SBclass, "<init>", "()V")`. Now you can use `jobject SBobject = env->NewObject(env, SBclass, SBconstructor)`.

Comment: "I want it to fill a received String."  Java can't fill any C++ data structure except a [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), which you should consider using. "I don't want the Java code to return a value": This is an odd requirement, except if you were using a ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a `byte[]`, which is a mutable type, instead of jumping through the hoops of creating a `StringBuilder` passing it, and then calling `toString` when you get it back. Or having problems with encoding.

You create a `byte[]` like this:

```
jclass mainClass = env->FindClass("Main");
jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "setValue", "([B)V");

jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(7);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, method, bytes);
const char* str = (char*) env->GetByteArrayElements(bytes, 0);

printf(str);

//... use here

env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bytes, (jbyte*) str, JNI_ABORT);
```

And then you can fill it from Java like this:

```
public static void setValue(byte[] val) {
    String someString = "Hello!"; // some string
    byte[] bytes = someString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, val, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

---

I realized later that you can also use a direct byte buffer, which is perhaps even simpler than using a `byte[]`. It allows you to create a Java usable view over an arbitrary block of bytes:

```
jmethodID method = env->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "setValue", "(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)V");

const int buff_size = 1024;
char buff[buff_size]; // Creating a view over this block of memory
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, method, env->NewDirectByteBuffer(buff, buff_size));
//... use buff
```

And in Java:

```
public static void setValue(ByteBuffer buff) {
    String someString = "Hello!";
    buff.put(someString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
}
```

Comment: ASCII is very rarely the right character encoding. I think, for Android, UTF-8 is typical. But, I agree that `byte[]` makes things a lot easier with JNI.

Comment: StandardCharsets.US_ASCII requires api 19...
also for some reason im getting Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr crashes...it seems that every row is executed correctly but when the function quits, it suddenly crahes

Comment: @danidin You can also pass a string to `getBytes` but with that overload it can throw an exception. I can only speculate about the SIGILL, maybe the calling convention you're using is incorrect, so make sure to use the header file generated by `javah`.